# Facebook comments widget - App ID

Tags: comments, facebook

I have installed a [Facebook comments widget](http://3doordigital.com/wordpress/plugins/facebook-comments/?utm_source=WordPress&utm_medium=Admin&utm_campaign=Facebook%2bComments) that seems to be working just fine without the App ID. Is the App ID really necessary? What advantages will it give me if I add it?

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to moderate comments. Here's the relevant quote from [the doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)'s Moderation Tools section:

> Doing this enables a moderator interface on Facebook where comments from all plugins administered by your app id can be easily moderated together.

I personally never used the moderation tool, but it is available if you need it, which is nearly always the case if you are working with a corporate client who would want to have control over all site content, including comments.